# EJB/JPA: Is it called JPQL or EJBQL?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, jpql

Is the JPA query language called JPQL or EJBQL? I keep reading about them here and there, JPQL seems to appear slightly more often, but frameworks like JBoss Seam use EJBQL everywhere, so which one is **the** one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EJBQL is the obsolete query language that was included with the EJB 2.1 spec.

JPQL is the new query language that is used with JPA and supercedes EJBQL. JPQL supports all the old EJBQL language, including many deprecated parts.

Comment: JPQL is the third in a series of 'java only query languages that  attempt to replace SQL' that will very likely also be deprecated.